# Is $f(x) = \frac{x}{x-1}, x \gt 1$ invertible?

Tags: functions

I think since the function is not defined for $x \lt 1$ so this function is not invertible.
I had also proved that this is an one to one function but is this an onto function too?

Comment: It is an invertible function from $(1,\infty)$ to $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @Alan in the title it says its not

Comment: The domain or range of a function can be $anything$. If the domain and range  of $f $
 are each $(1,\infty)$ then $f$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the  codomain of the function.
After differentiating the function we understand that it is a strictly decreasing function.At x=1+ we get f(x) tends to infinity.
x/(x-1)=1+1/x-1 ,so as x tends to infinity function tends to 1
Thus range is (1,inf).

Answer (score 0):

If you compute $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{(x-1)^{2}}$ then you will see that it is $<0\,\forall\, x>1$ Hence you can say that it is one-one. And $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x-1} > 1$ hence it is onto. So since it is a bijection on $(1,\infty)$ you can say that it is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Let x >1;

$f(x):=1+\dfrac{1}{x-1};$

$g(x):=x-1$ is stricly increasing.

$\dfrac{1}{g(x)}$ is strictly decreasing.